# type error positional argument self missing

Tags: python, class

why can't i access Classroom object?
It shows:
next_scene_name = start_scene.enter() #error
TypeError: enter() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

please explain what mistake i did.

```
#class
class Engine(object):    #(map_object_with_classroom, player_object)
    def __init__(self,map_object,player_object):
        self.map_object = map_object
        self.player_object = player_object

    def play(self):
        print('\n')
        print('test ok')
        start_scene = self.map_object.begin()
        end_scene = self.map_object.Senario['auditorium']

        while start_scene != end_scene:
            next_scene_name = start_scene.enter() #error
            start_scene = self.map_object.next_scene(next_scene_name)

class Player(object):
    Student_influence = 20
    Staff_influence = 20
    principle_influence = 20
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name


class Scene(object):
    def enter(self):
        print("test")


class ClassRoom(Scene):
    def enter(self):
        print('test ok!')
        return 'sportsclub'

class SportsClub(Scene):
    def enter(self):
        print('test ok!')
        return 'scienceclub'

class ScienceClub(Scene):
    def enter(self):
        print('test ok!')
        return 'canteen'

class Canteen(Scene):
    def enter(self):
        print('test ok!')
        return 'auditorium'

class Auditorium(Scene):
    def enter(self):
        print('test ok!')
        return 'finished'

class Finished(Scene):
    def enter(self):
        print('test ok!')
        return None

class Map(object):
    Senario = {'finished':Finished, 'classroom':ClassRoom,'sportclub':SportsClub, 'scienceclub':ScienceClub, 'canteen':Canteen, 'auditorium':Auditorium}

    def __init__(self,start_scene):
        self.start_scene = start_scene

    def begin(self):
        return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)

    def next_scene(self,scene_name):
        nxt = self.Senario.get(scene_name)
        return nxt

#--------------------------------
#function
#test
map_object = Map('classroom')
new_player = Player('Lancer')
new_game = Engine(map_object,new_player)
new_game.play()
```

when i print start_scene it shows  what is that? but when i print an instance of ClassRoom class it shows <**main**.ClassRoom object>

Comment: Add `print(start_scene)` before the line with the error and compare the output you get with the one you observed for an *instance* of the class. From there try to figure out whether you are actually calling `enter()` on an *instance* of the class.

Comment: if I've traced your code through correctly, `start_scene` here ends up being `ClassRoom`, which is a *class*, not an instance of the class as I guess you wanted. But it's not clear how to fix because I don't know what arguments you wanted to pass to the constructor,

Comment: First of all, read [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). There, you'll see the convention to name classes with capital letter (e.g. `Player`) and instances with lower letter, e.g. `map_object`. Once you start following that, you will no longer make the mistake to have a class object in a variable named `start_scene`.

Comment: start_scene prints <class '__main__.ClassRoom'>. i now that is not an instance, i dont know what that is any why is it showing that way. an instant should print out some thing like : <__main__.Map object at 0x0328F2D0>

Comment: @PawanPs As it is saying, that is *the class itself*. `'classroom': ClassRoom`: here `ClassRoom` is *the class itself*. `ClassRoom()` would be an *instance of the class*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `next_scene`, you are returning `ClassRoom`, but not an *instance* of `ClassRoom`. For that, you'd need `return nxt()`, which then has a `self`

```py
class Map(object):
    Senario = {'finished':Finished, 'classroom':ClassRoom,'sportclub':SportsClub, 'scienceclub':ScienceClub, 'canteen':Canteen, 'auditorium':Auditorium}

    def __init__(self,start_scene):
        self.start_scene = start_scene

    def begin(self):
        return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)

    def next_scene(self,scene_name):
        # adding the parentheses here will call the class
        # creating an instance
        nxt = self.Senario.get(scene_name)()
        return nxt
```

As a small example:

```py
class X:
    def something(self):
        return 4


X.something()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: something() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

You haven't created any instance, and so `self` doesn't exist yet. However, if we change it to:

```py
x = X()
x.something()
4
```

A `self` gets created because the underlying class machinery will call a base implementation of `__init__`, without getting into the gory details